# Timed out waiting for async script result Selenium C# Protractor

Tags: c#, selenium, protractor-net

I'm trying to create an automation test script using Protractor.net for an AngularJS platform, with Selenium in C#. I've created the driver using the below code.

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
Ngdriver = new NgWebDriver(driver);
```

And then attempted to locate and element as follows:

```
Ngdriver.FindElement(NgBy.Model("vm.reference")).SendKeys("Test");
```

However, I'm receiving an exception: Timed out waiting for async script result after 45ms.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where/on which element is `ng-app` defined? Also, please show the rest of the test. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolved this by using the SetScriptTimeout.

```
ngDriver.Manage().Timeouts().SetScriptTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

Comment: Hi, i have the same issue while running protractor script with appium, but it wasn't resolved yet ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37070680/timed-out-waiting-for-asynchronous-script-result-while-executing-protractor-scri