# Timed out waiting for asynchronous script result while executing protractor scripts with appium

Tags: ajax, jasmine, protractor, appium, end-to-end

I have a problem while running more than one test in protractor : Timed out waiting for asynchronous script result after 60010 s 
The code of tutorial script which is executed just after the login script : [image: Here the code of login script + Tutorial script]

Here the code i'm using in my config file from [A Code proposed in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33698085/timed-out-waiting-for-async-script-result-selenium-c-sharp-protractor) but it didn't solve my problem !

```
onPrepare: function() {
  return browser.getProcessedConfig().then(function(config) {
    var browserName = config.capabilities.browserName;
    browser.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(60000);

  });
```

[image: Here the config file]

*PS : Even if i put an incorrect location for the element i have the error of time out and not this element cannot be found ! as if that line of code "the click into tutorial button" is never executed*

- Is it because tutorial make an ajax call ?

[image: Error]
Here my html code :

```
</div></md-card-content> </md-card><!-- end ngIf: !expandChart --> </div> </div> </div></md-content> </div></div> <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID --> <!--<script>--> <!--!function(A,n,g,u,l,a,r){A.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l,A[l]=A[l]||function(){--> <!--(A[l].q=A[l].q||[]).push(arguments)},A[l].l=+new Date,a=n.createElement(g),--> <!--r=n.getElementsByTagName(g)[0],a.src=u,r.parentNode.insertBefore(a,r)--> <!--}(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');--> <!--ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-X');--> <!--ga('send', 'pageview');--> <!--</script>--> <script src="scripts/vendor.js"></script> <script src="cordova.js"></script> <script src="scripts/scripts.js"></script> <script src="https://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/sha1.js"></script> <script src="https://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/sha256.js"></script> <script src="https://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/components/enc-base64-min.js"></script> <div class="introjs-overlay" style="top: 0;bottom: 0; left: 0;right: 0;position: fixed;opacity: 0.8;"></div><div class="introjs-helperLayer " style="width: 538px; height:366px; top:64px;left: 195px;"></div><div class="introjs-tooltipReferenceLayer" style="width: 538px; height:366px; top:64px;left: 195px;"><div class="introjs-tooltip" style="left: 546px;"><div class="introjs-tooltiptext">Watchlist view. Swipe the row in the grid to the left to show the delete action.</div><div class="introjs-bullets"><ul><li><a class="active" href="javascript:void(0);" data-stepnumber="1">&nbsp;</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-stepnumber="2">&nbsp;</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-stepnumber="3">&nbsp;</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-stepnumber="4">&nbsp;</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-stepnumber="5">&nbsp;</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-stepnumber="6">&nbsp;</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-stepnumber="7">&nbsp;</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-stepnumber="8">&nbsp;</a></li></ul></div><div class="introjs-progress" style="display: none;"><div class="introjs-progressbar" style="width:12.5%;"></div></div><div class="introjs-arrow left" style="display: inherit;"></div><div class="introjs-tooltipbuttons"><a class="introjs-button introjs-skipbutton" href="javascript:void(0);">Don't show it again!</a><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="introjs-button introjs-prevbutton introjs-disabled" tabindex="-1">Previous</a><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="introjs-button introjs-nextbutton">Next</a></div></div></div></body></html>​
```

[image: Appium log]

Comment: Yeah, it's an angular site

Comment: Does it continuously poll $http or $timeout?

Comment: Sorry what you mean by poll $http or $timeout?

Comment: It's an Angular thing, ask your developers.  If it does, the page will never complete synchronizing and Protractor will never know the page is done loading so jasmine will timeout. Our app used to do that

Comment: Like a keepAlive service to let users stay logged in for a certain amount of time, or anything like that

Comment: In that case how can we solve that problem ?

Comment: If that is the case, ideal solution would be to ask them if they can switch that service to use Interval.js (part of Angular).  Otherwise you'd have to turn on browser.ignoreSynchronization and treat your app as if it's non-angular

Comment: i tried with browser.ignoreSynchronization= true but it's not a good solution element will not be found and i need in my future test the angular effect.

Comment: @Emma Hi, I found this question in your comment. So I will try to help. --- First change `element(by.buttonText('Next'))`  to `$('.introjs-nextbutton')` --- Second `EC.stalenessOf...` it look like you are waiting for the button to be NOT attached to DOM then click on it... this doesn't make any sense for me. Try to remove `EC.stalenessOf` then simply do `tutorial.click()`. Give these suggests a try and tell me if it works ;)

Comment: @LinhPham, Hi Ok thanks i'll try and tell you ;)

Comment: @LinhPham : sorry i still have the same error :(

Comment: @Emma, can you somehow share me full code of that describe block after you have adjusted?

Comment: Ok i'll share the config and the test for login + tutorial

Comment: @LinhPham : i update the code in the question with screenshots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i tried to solve my problem by adding this call back

```
describe("long asynchronous specs", function() {
    beforeEach(function(done) {
      done();
    }, 10000);
    });
```

Here is a link from jasmine [Asynchronous_Support](http://jasmine.github.io/2.4/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support) that help me understand time out problems. 
Hope that can help you,

Answer (score 3):

**1. Regarding with route check**

In case after first spec, user got logged in and the route changed. Make sure all are navigated before any test executed.

```
expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('#/the_route_of_logged_in'); 
// '#/' is just illustration. You can remove it to make it shorter
// => like this ...toContain('the_route_of_logged_in');
```

**2. Regarding with click on tutorial**

```
browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(tutorial), 10000);
```

Do the `browser.wait` with EC for click-able button before attempt to click it (it seem like you got good approach here)

**=> SUMMING UP** you can give this a try:

```
'user strict';

var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

describe('tutorials', function () {

    it('should make click into tutorial button', function () {

        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('the_route_of_logged_in');

        var tutorial = $('.introjs-nextbutton'); 
        browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(tutorial), 8000, 'Timed out');
        tutorial.click();

        browser.sleep(8080); // regardless we are not reaching this point. But I will suggest to reduce this sleep time like 1000 (1s).
    });
});
```

**3. (optional) in case 2 points above does not help**

In your all of your spec `login-spec.js` and `tutorial-spec.js`. Add `process.nextTick(done);` in a `afterAll()` block to ensure if there are no any Jasmine Reporters being stuck after a spec.

```js
describe('foo', function(){

  afterAll(function(done){
    process.nextTick(done);
  });  

  it('should bar...', function() {});
}
```

**P.S.** Beware that I am totally have no clue if my suggestions/approach could help. As debugging with e2e-test always painful... because we are always likely not knowing "where are the errors come from". So all I can do is giving you suggestions. 
*(sometimes it took me hours to just observe the behaviors of browser to identify an issue of e2e-test)*

And **DO NOT COPY PASTE** my code into your code. I typed it with the images you provide, I can make some typos there.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, i'll try and let you know ;)

Comment: @Emma, I've added 3rd suggestion. If error still present, please copy and paste it here. I will check on this again tomorrow, cheer! ;)

Comment: Ok i'll check it because until now error is still present .. 
Thanks a lot for all your tries ;)

Comment: @Emma, is it like we still have the same error output?

Comment: Yes but the problem is becoming more visible, if i do only login script with this one `expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('#/quotes'); ` some time it fails and when i add a `browser.sleep(time_to_wait);` not too big, and when i put it big enough (for eg: > 8000). I got this Time out error !

Comment: with `browser.waitForAngular();`  used in login test the `expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('#/quotes');` is passed then inside tutorial test (we are sure now that this is the page we are searching) always we have the time out issue (using all 3 suggestions)

Comment: @Emma, very useful information, I got 2 questions --- regarding with `browser.sleep(time_to_wait);` can you count how long it is after login and the error of time out appearr? --- please try to do a manual login and use a clock to check how long it took to finish the login _(the route + view got changed and updated)_?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111649/discussion-between-emna-and-linh-pham).

Answer (score 2):

Add  parameter to conf.js under capabilities:

```
maxSessions: 1,
```

it should help.
Also your timeoutinterval might be too high 30000 should be enough.

Or on prepare change line to :

```
browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000);
```

@EDIT:
change to sth similar to this found something like this

> 5. baseUrl is 10.0.2.2 instead of localhost because it is used to access the localhost of the host machine in the android
>      emulator/device

```
baseUrl: 'http://10.0.2.2:' + (process.env.HTTP_PORT || '8000'),
```

Capabilities new command:

```
 newCommandTimeout: 60
```

Also use of promises might be helpfull instead of timeouts

```
someethingToDo.click().then(function(){

  return somethingToDo.click();

}).then(function(){
    //morecode
});
```

Comment: Same error with the first answer ! i'll try the second ;)

Comment: Sorry even with the second option i still have the same issue ! for login it's done that click option it's not working at all in home page

Comment: I have a question. You are using protractor or somekind pytractor or protractor.net ?
 I had similar problem while i was working on PyTractor, and i had to change it for clean ProTractor.

Comment: i'm using protractor to test a site in a mobile device (ipad simulator)

Comment: I edit main answer check it mb it will work :), and tell me you have homepage visable on mobile or not ?

Comment: Still same issue :( The problem is that home page is displayed and stay a lot of time but the second test is not executed (i have even tried to put that test in the same file of spec and in the same `it('....',function() {
....................}) `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111231/discussion-between-hikaryu-and-emna).

Answer (score 2):

I think you might have an issue with how your timeouts are set up. Remove all timeout references from your config file and try something like this (adjust accordingly to include other configurations as needed):

```
exports.config = {
    allScriptsTimeout: 60000,
    getPageTimeout: 30000,
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 62000,
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it but i still have a jasmine `DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL`