# Waitforangular call timed out if there are no http call on page

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, protractor, angular-promise

We are using protractor framework for E2E testing.

We have seen an odd behavior that `waitforAngular();` call getting timed out if there are no http call on page.
  It is working fine if we are using sleep call in place of `waitforAngular();`  call.

Please share your views to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add :

```
 describe("long asynchronous specs", function() {
    beforeEach(function(done) {
     waitforAngular();
      done();
    }, 10000);
   // Your code here 
   waitforAngular();
   afterEach(function(done) {
     waitforAngular();
      done();
    }, 10000);
  }
```

Comment: Could you please explain this logic a bit , why to add this logic and how does it helps here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37070680/timed-out-waiting-for-asynchronous-script-result-while-executing-protractor-scri
check the answer i have accepted in this question and the link for different option in jasmine asynchrnous support.